# Ugly artifacts when using Helvetica (tgheros), Beamer, and pdflatex

Tags: beamer, fonts

First, please note that this question pertains to pdflatex, not xelatex or lualatex.  I cannot use any solution involving packages such as fontspec.

I'm trying to use Helvetica or a similar font in beamer for both text and math.  Unfortunately, I consistently get ugly output.  Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{tgheros}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\neg(A+1=B)\Longrightarrow A+1\ne B\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output I get:

[image]

There are two things wrong here.  First, the thickness of the + sign does not match that of the letters.  Second, there is a glitch in the `\Longrightarrow` (which presumably is composed of an equals sign and arrow in mismatched fonts).

I somewhat accidentally discovered that I can get much better looking output with:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tgheros}
```

Using both lmodern and tgheros in that order makes most equations look much better, but the artifacts get worse.  Here is an example:

[image]

Now the + and = look much better, as they are matched to the font.  But now the glitches in `\Longrightarrow` are even worse.  Also, the `\ne` sign has the slash slightly off-center (though I suppose I could live with it if necessary).

My question is how to get the best of both worlds:  Most symbols like + and = well matched to the font of the letters, but ugly artifacts also minimized.

Comment: Try with `\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks for the suggestion.  That fixes \Longright arrow, but then the less than and greater than signs look horrible and completely incongruous with `\ge` and `\le`.

Answer (score 3):

To get around the problem with the glitch in the arrow you can redefine the arrow to use cmr for the equal sign instead of cmss (which doesn't fit exactly:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tgheros}

\renewcommand\Longrightarrow{%
 \mathrel{%
  \mbox{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont=}}%
 \joinrel\Rightarrow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[\neg(A+1=B)\Longrightarrow A+1\ne B\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That fixes the most serious problem.  I'm still going to leave this open for a bit in case someone has a more systematic solution.  After all, wanting to use helvetica or a similar highly-readable sans-serif font in a presentation has to be a reasonably common requirement, so I'm hoping there is a package or option that just does this makes everything look good.

Comment: Also, how would I do this for `\Longleftarrow`?  Simply flipping around what you've done--namely `\Leftarrow\joinrel\mbox{...}`--seems to leave a gap between the `\Leftarrow` and = sign.

Comment: You can use `\renewcommand\Longleftarrow{\mathrel{\Leftarrow \joinrel\mathrel{\mbox{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont=}}}}`

Comment: @user3188445 Sorry I meant yesterday `\renewcommand\Longleftarrow{\Leftarrow\joinrel\mathrel{\mbox{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont=}}}`  The important bit it that both parts must be a mathrel.