# Why does the render of the pdf look dirty?

Tags: pdftex, rendering

This happened suddenly and I don't remember doing anything to mess up with that. I'm using TeX Live and pdfLaTeX and when I compile the problem the symbols look off, like they're not perfectly aligned. Any idea what could have triggered this? Example:

[image]

This is the code, however I've tried with other classes and still get the same rendering. I also tried removing the settings for the text spaces and doesn't do anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4wide]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs, mathtools, mathalfa}
\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage[dvistyle, colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{stretch/.initial=1}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\topmargin -0.5 cm
\linespread{1.3}
\evensidemargin 0cm
\oddsidemargin 0cm
\textheight 22.3 cm
\marginparwidth = 55pt
\textwidth 16cm
\setlength{\parindent}{0.7 cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{1.5 cm}

\begin{document}
    
asdasdasdasd This is a text document. Apparently it looks good but I see the letters a little off.\\
$\Longrightarrow$
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

This is the output for the pdflatex terminal:

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [a4wide].

(./document.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stmaryrd/Ustmry.fd)

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/stmry/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `U/stmry/m/n' instead on input line 35.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(./document.out) (./document.out)

Package todonotes Warning: The length marginparwidth is less than 2cm and will 
most likely cause issues with the appearance of inserted todonotes. The issue c
an be solved by adding a line like \setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm} prior to 
loading the todonotes package. on input line 35.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/se-pdfdoc.def) [1

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file pdftex.map): cannot open font map file
] (./document.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ) 
Output written on document.pdf (1 page, 11597 bytes).
Transcript written on document.log.
```

Comment: Looks like a font encoding issue, maybe you added a package that changes font settings. It could also be a viewer issue, which you can test by using a different viewer. Without any code it is difficult to diagnose however. Could you provide a complete document that is as small as possible and that still shows this issue? Start with `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}$a(n)=(-1)$\end{document}`, test if it shows the issue, and if not then expand from there by adding the documentclass, packages and settings from your original document piece by piece.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The screenshot that you provide at the link looks normal to me, except for the double arrow at the bottom left that is rendered poorly. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280966/ugly-artifacts-when-using-helvetica-tgheros-beamer-and-pdflatex for a better `\Longrightarrow`

Comment: I suspect you are using bitmap fonts, show the last part of the terminal output from pdflatex where it lists the fonts used

Comment: @DavidCarlisle might be right. I edited the post with the outcome. What can I do?

Comment: oh not what I expected `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file pdftex.map): cannot open font map file` your pdflatex is pretty broken it is  /usr/share so I assume the linux supplied one, try sudo update texlive or whatever linux  package manager you use

Comment: That fixed it thank you very much. I'm amazed it took so litle to fix it.